# Getting the title of an image and display it as HTML using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a img which is displaying fine, however I now want to hide the image (display: none) and get the value of its title and display that in its parent div instead, using JQuery. I'm sure it's relatively simple, I'm just drawing a massive mind blank at the moment.

```
<div class="cardBrand image">
  <img class="card-logo" title="Mastercard" src="/hosted/assets/payment-logo/mastercard-debit.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert the title after the image like

```js
$('.cardBrand.image img').after(function() {
  return this.title;
}).hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cardBrand image">
  <img class="card-logo" title="Mastercard" src="/hosted/assets/payment-logo/mastercard-debit.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks again @Arun. Perfect answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the title of the image using `$('#img-id').attr('title');` and then use it to set the html using `$('#div-id').html($('#img-id').attr('title'));` 
**Note :** You can use the class also. But, it will change all the div with the same class. It is recommended that you use an id for the div for these  purposes

Answer (score 0):

```
var image_title=$('.card-logo').attr('title'); // get title of image
$('.card-logo').hide(); // hide image
$('.cardBrand').text(image_title); // set title in parent div
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var imgTitle="<span>" + $(".card-logo").attr("title") + "</span>";
$(imgTitle).insertAfter($(".card-logo"));
$(".card-logo").hide();
```